# SFML, технический вопрос про белый квадрат

Tags: c++, sfml

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
void loadSprite(Sprite &sprite)
{
    Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("texture.bmp");

    sprite.setTexture(texture);
}
```

Мне хорошо известно, что данный код некорректен, и целевой спрайт после вызова такой функции при отрисовке будет белым, потому что спрайт ссылается на текстуру, а текстура была локальным объектом функции.

Меня интересует другое.

Почему при отрисовке спрайта отрисовывается белый квадрат, а не падает все приложение из-за ошибки сегментации?

Я могу предположить две причины:

1. Деструктор текстуры сбрасывает связи во всех спрайтах, которые ссылаются на данную текстуру. Это предположение мне кажется маловероятным, потому что иначе текстуре придется хранить связи с каждым спрайтом.
2. Текстуры (и многое другое) аллоцируются внутри `SFML`, то есть при помощи менеджера памяти/ресурсов самой `SFML`. Но в этом случае я не совсем понимаю, как спрайты узнают о том, что текстура перестала существовать. То есть, не ясно, как спрайт связывается с текстурой: посредством указателя, ID или еще как-то.

Очень хотел бы разобраться в том, как это работает внутри, чтобы лучше понимать, где могут возникнуть проблемы и как их решать.

Comment: А посмотреть исходники пробовали? [setTexture](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Sprite.cpp#L75)
`m_texture = &texture;`, объекта уже нет, но пока память не затрётся другими данными, всё будет работать. А может и не так. [Texture::~Texture()](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp#L109). С SFML не работал, с OpenGL поверхностно знаком

Comment: @vegorov, я как-то не догадался, да и думал, что все намного сложнее. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: "целевой спрайт после вызова такой функции при отрисовке будет белым" - совсем не обязательно. Результат работы непредсказуем. Разбираться, почему неопределенное поведение приводит к тем или иным конкретным результатам обычно является пустой тратой времени.